# Continuous Time Markov Chain Remaining in a State

Tags: markov-chains

I am faced with the following question: given a Markov Chain with three possible states, $1,2,3$, and transition rates:

$$\alpha(1,2)=\alpha(2,3)=1,\:\alpha(2,1)=\alpha(3,2)=4$$

and the assumption that $X_0=1$, what is the probability that $X_t=3$ for all $t\in[2,3]$?

I have already found the probability that $X_2=3$ by deriving the transition matrix $P_t$ (which I got by calculating eigenvalues and solving for $P_t=e^{tA}=Qe^{tD}Q^{-1}$).

$$P_t=\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
\frac{16}{21}&\frac{4}{21}&\frac{1}{21}\\
\frac{16}{21}&\frac{4}{21}&\frac{1}{21}\\
\frac{16}{21}&\frac{4}{21}&\frac{1}{21}\\
\end{array}\right]
+e^{-3t}\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
\frac{1}{6}&-\frac{1}{12}&-\frac{1}{12}\\
\frac{1}{3}&\frac{1}{6}&\frac{1}{6}\\
\frac{1}{6}&-\frac{1}{12}&-\frac{1}{12}\\
\end{array}\right]
+e^{-7t}\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
\frac{1}{14}&-\frac{3}{28}&\frac{1}{28}\\
\frac{3}{7}&\frac{9}{14}&\frac{4}{14}\\
\frac{4}{7}&-\frac{6}{7}&\frac{2}{7}\\
\end{array}\right]
$$

I'm stuck as to where to go from here. I figure I need to somehow integrate over $[2,3]$, but I'm not sure precisely how to do that. Any suggestions would be sincerely appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: A little fluffy bunny dies every time you post a picture of mathematical expressions.

Comment: I love bunnies though... :( 

In all seriousness, I didn't fancy retyping multiple matrices. Please forgive me.

Comment: Thanks for the edit.